# Value of Data-id to be value of parent element

Tags: jquery, html

I just want the `data-id` value to be what's written in the `textarea` means parent element.

```
<textarea aria-label="Add a comment…" placeholder="Add a comment…" class="addcomment_ta" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id="comment_i" name="comment_content" id="editable_comment" data-id='TEXTAREA VALUE'></textarea>
```

Comment: For what reason? Why not just read the `value` property from the element and save yourself the time?

Comment: Please note you use `id` multiple times

Comment: I am in such situation cant use value but thank you

Comment: Yeah i notice this now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$('.addcomment_ta').on("keyup", function() {
  $(this).attr('data-id', $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea aria-label="Add a comment…" placeholder="Add a comment…" class="addcomment_ta" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" name="comment_content" id="editable_comment" data-id='TEXTAREA VALUE'></textarea>
```

I created a `keyup` function in `JQuery` so every time you start typing the `data-id` updates!

**UPDATE:** The previous example does not work with copy, pasting and cutting. I changed the `keyup` to a `change`, `keyup`, `paste`

```js
$('.addcomment_ta').on('change keyup paste', function() {
  $(this).attr('data-id', $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea aria-label="Add a comment…" placeholder="Add a comment…" class="addcomment_ta" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" name="comment_content" id="editable_comment" data-id='TEXTAREA VALUE'></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much.

Comment: No, problem! Can you please approve my answer! @ShirazAhmad

Comment: Yeah did it. Thanks again!